# If I open explorer.exe first, then run cmd.exe, the init path for cmd.exe would be same with current path in explorer.exe

Tags: command-line, windows-explorer, path

I'm using Win XP in my company. I encountered a wonder thing:

1. I open an explorer.exe window.
2. Just enter a directory (for example, C:\Windows).
3. Run cmd.exe (Win+R, then issue cmd.exe)

The init path will change to the current path in explorer (C:\Windows) automatically!

It's a good feature, I want use it in my home as well. However, I don't know how to configure this. I checked the registry configuration information, and it same with my PC. I also do many searches by Google, but most of result are talking about add "Open commmand prompt here" to pop menu of folder.

If you know anything about this, please kindly share me. Thanks!

PS: if I didn't open any explore.exe window, then run cmd.exe, the path would be the "Desktop".

Comment: When I run cmd.exe the directory is set to my current user directory (C:\Documents and Settings\User) - presumably this is currently the same for you on your home machine?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Vista/7 then try Shift + Right Click on the folder and `Open Command Window Here`

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that! Faster!

Answer (score 1):

I never seen something like that. That would be so cool.

Otherways you could just add a "Open commmand prompt here" shortcut on the right click menu http://www.petri.co.il/add_command_prompt_here_shortcut_to_windows_explorer.htm

Comment: Actually, I know the tip for "Open command prompt here". Anyway, thanks for your advise!

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 10 (idk if in other windows works) you can type `cmd` in the path input and press enter, this will open a cmd in the actual folder.